# Creating tabs in aspx for application forms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, tabs

http://eduvark.com/images/Manipal-University-Application-Form.jpg

(I do not own the above link. Link has been used for illustration purpose only and not for commercial use without permission)

I need to create tab-like structure as shown in the image. I have the entire application form but I just need to create those tabs. I couldn't attach code snippets because the form is too large with multiple pages.

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use Jquery tabs and customize Jquery.ui css file for changing backrgound image

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use the jquery tabs and if they dont help in this scenario. then you can use

ajaxcontroltoolkit tab
find it here and then let me know.
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/tabs/tabs.aspx
plus the telerik controls also have a very good and customizable tab strip control but they are not available for free the ajaxcontroltoolkit is available for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by many ways by jQuery or by Ajax control toolkit. I will show here jQuery approach ([refer this](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)). Download all necessary files from [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!zThemeParams=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). Extract all the files and place jQuery ui, and css files on your application and link them to page as below

```
<script src="../Scripts/myapp/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../Styles/myapp/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../Scripts/myapp/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you want to change background image of the tab you add below style on the page to overwrite in built css by putting below style in page header

```
.ui-tabs-panel {background-image:url('image.jpg') !important;}
```

Hope this helps you.